# possible bug in django models

Tags: django, django-models, models

models.py:

```
class root(models.Model):
      uid_string = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True) 

class tree(models.Model):
      uid_string = models.ForeignKey(root, to_field='uid_string', db_column='uid_string')

class shrub(models.Model):
      uid_string = models.ForeignKey(root, to_field='uid_string')
```

obviously, the column in `shrub` will be `uid_string_id` while the column in `tree` will bee `uid_string`. the _id appendix is supressed.

If I now do a

```
rootentry = root(uid_string = "text")
root.save()
```

I get different behaviour doing the following queries:

```
>>> shrubentry = shrub(uid_string_id = rootentry.uid_string)
>>> treeentry = tree(uid_string = rootentry.uid_string)                                                             
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                  
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 328, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 318, in __set__
    self.field.name, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name))
ValueError: Cannot assign "'text'": "tree.uid_string" must be a "root" instance.
>>>
```

obviously `rootentry.uid_string` is `text`

Answer (score 2):

Django is behaving just as expected. To understand why we'll start with a look at the ways to pass keyword arguments to a model class' constructor in case of a foreign key relationship.

1. Use the name of the relationship (`uid_string`). In this case, you have to pass an *instance* of the related model (`uid_string = rootentry`).
2. Use the name of the database field (`uid_string_id`). Here you have to pass a value of an appropriate *type*. So if the FK points to an integer field, pass an integer; if it points to text, pass a text instance etc.

Now let us look at your code. We'll start with the **first line**:

```
shrubentry = shrub(uid_string_id = rootentry.uid_string)
shrubentry.save() # Succeeds
```

You have created a relation between `shrub` and `root` but have also specified a custom `to_field` to link to. Since this column is a text field you are able to pass the `rootentry.uid_string` as the value of the `uid_string_id` keyword argument (mechanism #2 listed above).

There is another way to express what you did above, without using the field name as the keyword argument. That will be to use the name of the relationship and pass an instance of root (mechanism #1 listed above).

```
shrubentry = shrub(uid_string = rootentry)
shrubentry.save() # Succeeds
```

Now let us take a look at the **second line**.

```
treeentry = tree(uid_string = rootentry.uid_string) # Raises error.
# ValueError: Cannot assign "'text'": "tree.uid_string" must be a "root" instance.
```

This line is different from the first line. You are using mechanism #1 (relationship name) and therefore Django expects an instance of `root` as the value of the keyword argument. If you switch to mechanism #2 (field name):

```
treeentry = tree(uid_string_id = rootentry.uid_string)
treeentry.save() # Succeeds
```

Now comes the interesting part. Try this:

```
treeentry = tree(uid_string_id = rootentry.id)  # No problem
treeentry.save() # Blows up
# IntegrityError: ...
# DETAIL:  Key (uid_string)=(2) is not present in table "app_root".
```

The first line of the above snippet works. But when you try to save it the database looks for a key "2" (i.e. `rootentry.id`) in the _uid_string_ column of the `root` table. Since it is not there, the `save()` fails.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as I understood it, you specify the relationship using    to_field='uid_string'    and simply the NAME of the column by    db_column=""    . Leaving out the   to_field    would reference to the primary key (id). Am I wrong?

Comment: You have it right. Leaving out the `to_field` is correct. My mistake. I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But please take a look again. Both models have a `to_field` to specify the column. The models are the same except for the column name defined by `db_column`.

Comment: @tpm: have updated answer above. Added `save()` calls to better illustrate my point. See if it helps.

Comment: thanks again. Your comments really made me understand things better. I tried your examples in a testapp and yes, it just works as you show it. BUT: there's only one thing that confuses me: using the models shown in my first snippet, the table `tree` in the database has no column named `uid_string_id` but simply `uid_string` (whilst the `shrub` table has a column named `uid_string_id`). Nevertheless, `treeentry = tree(uid_string_id = rootentry.uid_string)` works, although there's no column named `uid_string_id` in `tree`. Is django processing the `_id` suffix in a special way?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with foreignkeys, you need to use object instance like below.

```
treeentry = tree(uid_string = rootentry)
```

BTW, use CamelCase for Class names. Please read http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/